# Php get variable from required file

Tags: php, require

I have a class:

```
class My_Class {

    private $playlist_table_name;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->playlist_table_name = "something";

        require_once('markup.php');

    }

}
```

How do I access $playlist_table_name from markup.php file?

I tried using: $this->playlist_table_name, but I get:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the variable like that, you will need to mark it as `public`

```
class My_Class {
    public $playlist_table_name;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->playlist_table_name = "something";

        require_once('markup.php');
    }
}
```

You are then going to want to instantiate the class before attempting to use it.

```
$MyClass = new My_Class;

echo $MyClass->playlist_table_name;
```

That will allow you to `echo` out the value.

Comment: OP is asking  about how to access from inside the class context. If he's accessing from inside, Private will do. $this can be used for that. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Yes, but I think the error he's getting for using $this will remain even after he makes the variable Public.

Comment: Hence my solution not using `$this`. You cannot use `$this` outside of the class structure.